# Adding Images to a ListView from SQL using Assets Folder for Images

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview, android-assets

I'm making Android app that has this database in it:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snacks (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT, " +
                "disc TEXT, " +
                "photo TEXT, " +
                "thumb TEXT, " +
                "ingre TEXT, " +
                "howto TEXT, " +
                "info TEXT, " +
                "snackId INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("name", "Name 1");
    values.put("disc", "here is the description");
    values.put("photo", "stub.png");
    values.put("thumb", "stub.png");
    values.put("ingre", "the ingredients of the snack");
    values.put("howto", "how to make this thing");
    values.put("info", "basically its this much calorie and such and such");
    db.insert("snacks", "name", values);...............etc etc ......`
```

In one of my Activities I have a search bar that can query the database. The results are displayed in a listview. When I click one item in the list I get the details for it, including a Photo.
My Photos are in the Assets Folder. I want to retrieve the photo from the assets folder and display a thumbnail of it. I tried using the Assets manager like this

```
public void search(View view) {
  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, disc, thumb FROM snacks WHERE name LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});

  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
  this, 
  R.layout.cook_tab_snackslist, 
  cursor, 
  new String[] {"name", "disc"},        
  new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.disc});

  Thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb);
  try {
   InputStream bitmap=getAssets().open(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thumb")));
   Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
   Thumb.setImageBitmap(bit);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I realize this isn't correct and I'm getting the following error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 7
```

What can I do? Am I even going about this the correct way?

Comment: The answer from slukian is correct. Just to expand on it - the position of a cursor returned by a query is set to 'before' the first record. As the first record of a cursor has an 'index' of 0, it makes sense that the cursor position is -1. As slukian says, you need to move the cursor position either by calling `moveToFirst` or simply `moveToNext`.

Comment: Well now , when i search for something that isn't there , the app crashes with this error : 
.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line after you make the query(you should also check before to make sure the cursor isn't *null*):

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: Thanks, It stopped my error, but Nothing happens still, I can't seem to show the image in the listView...

Comment: Also now , if i query a letter that isn't in my list , the app crashes error report,.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: okay i fixed the new error after reading up : 
if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
         cursor.moveToFirst();
but still the thumbnail isn't showing up :( HELP!

Comment: @FirstLaw A simpler way to resolve the `CursorIndexOutOfBounds` is to use the method `cursor.moveToFirst()` which will return `false` if the cursor is empty. To make your images appear you'll have to implement your own `SimpleCursorAdapter` and in the method `bindView()` set the images for the rows.

Comment: Hello again, i'm sorry for being a noob , but if i just use cursor.moveTofirst() i get cursur nullfied error, so i have to use this if (cursor.getCount() == 1) { command first to get it normal , but ... then nothing shows up at all my main problem is i dont know what you mean by simplecursor adapter with method bind view.. do you mean i have to make a `SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(thumb)` command?, i dont know what u mean. sorry i'm a noob

Comment: @FirstLaw You said that you have an activity with a search bar and you display the results with a `ListView`. If you click on a result row do you start a new activity to show the details of that result row? And do you want to see the photo in the new activity?

Comment: well , I have made a searchbar , that presents my search results in a listView in the same activity it basically works like this tutorial step 3 : http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/
I want to add thumbnails to my listview ...
but i'm lost ... :( please help

Comment: @FirstLaw You'll have to implement your own adapter to bind the image to the `ImageView`, here is a piece of code to implement http://pastebin.com/fYCL57zi .

Comment: DUDE! YOU ARE A GENIUS !!!! thanks alot and sorry for being such a noob thanks again!!!!